# override java class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I am having the following example

```
public class Tester
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {

        new Tester().execute();

    }

    private void execute() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        //Java Class Loader
        ClassLoader baseClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        //Java custom Class Loader
        ClassLoader customClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
        Class<?> customClass = Class.forName("a.b.c.d.class", true, customClassLoader);

        //Java custom Class Loader
        ClassLoader customClassLoader = customClass.getClassLoader();

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(customClassLoader);

        //Java custom Class Loader
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        //Java Class Loader?????
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    }
}
```

Why after invoke

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(customClassLoader);
```

once I execute

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

I still get the java class loader and not my custom class loader.

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: *"override java class loader"*  ***Why?***  What are you trying to achieve by doing so?  There is almost certainly a better answer to be had than pursuing this strategy.

Comment: Because i am working with third party that uses old version of jaxb and my code is using jaxb from the rt.jar of java , so i can;t put it under endorse version , i want to wrap the section that i call the third party to work with my custom class path then after it to continue working with java class loader

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.setContextClassLoader` just sets a variable in `Thread`. Linking classes is still done from each class' class loader. It certainly doesn't change the class loader of any already loaded classes. All that it changes is the class loader returned by `Thread.getContextClassLoader`.

I'd suggest staying away from thread context class loader, and other thread-globals.

Comment: so how can i do this? or java doesn't allow to do it

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For example, I'm writing a Maven plugin that scans the codebase. Using `Field.getGenericType()` uses the default class loading strategy whereas elsewhere in my plugin I override and use a classloader that loads classes from the project target directory. This is why I, for one, would need this.